# Find current location of logged in user

Tags: users, location

How can I find out the current location of the logged in user? 
When a user is logged in I just want to search the current location of user and save the lat and long in the database . How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You a use a geo IP database/service to lookup a lat/long based on the user's IP address. There are many PHP API's out there to do this. The most popular Drupal module based solution is [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip).

> Smart IP identify visitor's geographical location
>   (longitude/latitude), country, region, city and postal code based on
>   the IP address of the user. These information will be stored at
>   session variable ($_SESSION) with array key 'smart_ip' and Drupal
>   $user->data object with array key 'geoip_location' of the user but
>   optionally it can be disabled (by role) at Smart IP admin page. Other
>   modules can use the function smart_ip_get_location($ip_address) that
>   returns an array containing the visitor's ISO 3166 2-character country
>   code, longitude, latitude, region (FIPS), city and postal code. It
>   provides a feature for you to perform your own IP lookup and admin
>   spoofing of an arbitrary IP for testing purposes.